# getColors.php won't give this notification when my query is wrong

Tags: javascript, php, html

**keuze.php**

This is the homepage. If the query is intentionally mistaken, it will     display an error message at the top of the page. The error code will be below in the **JavascriptFile.js**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Startopdracht Oussama</title>
    <?php
        include 'connection.php';
        include 'insertcode.php';



    ?>
    <script src="JavascriptFile.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body cz-shortcut-listen="true" id="auto_error_body">
<section>


    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="container">

            <h1>Selecteer een Automerk</h1>



            <form method="post">
                <select id="keuzelijst1" name="autos" onchange="ShowAutos(this.value)">
                    <?php

                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Autos";
                    $result = $conn->query($sql);

                    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                        // output data of each row
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            $Value = $row['AutoID'];
                            echo "<option value='$Value'>" . $row["AutoMerk"]. "</option>";

                        }
                    } else {
                        if ($result->num_rows == 0){

                            echo '<script type="text/javascript"> AutosError(); </script>';

                        }
                    }




                    $conn->close();
                    ?>

                </select>
                </br> </br>



                <div id="Autos">

                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>


        <div class="bgPulse">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

**getColors.php**

This page does not show a message if there is an error in the query. This is also the second window which will be shown with AJAX

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <?php
        include 'connection.php';
    ?>

    <script src="JavascriptFile.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body cz-shortcut-listen="true" id="kleur_error_body">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="container">
                <h1>Selecteer een Kleur</h1>
                <form method="post">
                    <select id="select_color" name="autokleur">
                    <?php

                        $AutoID = intval($_GET['AutoID']);

                    //    mysqli_select_db($con,"Kleuren, Autos");
                        $sql1= "SELECT * FROM Kleuren INNER JOIN Autos ON Kleuren.AutoID = Autos.AutoID WHERE Kleuren.AutoID = '".$AutoID."'";
                        $result1 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);

                        if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {

                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
                                $Kleur = $row['KleurID'];
                                $Kleur2 = $row['Kleur'];
                                echo "<option value='$Kleur'>" . $row["Kleur"] . "</option>";

                            }

                            echo "</br>";
                            echo "<input id='VerzendOpties' name='VerzendBT' type='submit' value='Verzenden'>";
                        }
                        else
                            {
                                if ($result1->num_rows == 0){

                                    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> KleurError(); </script>';

                                }
                            }

                     ?>


                    </select>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavascriptFile.js**

This is the file which will have the function for the error which i want to display

```
    function ShowAutos(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("Autos").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("Autos").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET","getColors.php?AutoID="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();


        }

    }




    function AutosError() {

        document.getElementById("auto_error_body").innerHTML = "<b>Er zijn geen auto's gevonden! </b></br><b>Je query is niet goed.</b></br>" + document.getElementById("auto_error_body").innerHTML;
    }

    function KleurError() {

        document.getElementById("kleur_error_body").innerHTML = "<b>Er zijn geen kleuren gevonden!  </b></br><b>Je query is niet goed.</b></br>" + document.getElementById("kleur_error_body").innerHTML;
    }



   **IF YOU NEED MORE INFORMATION JUST ASK ME PLEASE!**
```

Comment: Why dynamically call a javascript function on page load, just to display text, which you could display dynamically as well instead of the javascript? Also by "query is wrong" do you mean you don't get any results? Please explain the expected behaviour and the error / wrong behaviour you're getting.

Comment: How can I display it dynamically without javascript? I mean that when i change for example "Kleuren" to "Kleur" that it will give me a message above. The thing is that I WANT the message to appear. If I change for example the query for the cars from "Autos" to "Auto" it will give me a message above the page which will state "Er zijn geen auto's gevonden, Je query is niet goed".

Answer (score 0):

Why does your 'getColors.php' file include head elements and all the rest? When you inject it into the keuze.php page, you'll have multiple head elements, as well as loads of 'script' elements importing JavascriptFile.js every time.

Your 'getColors' file should only return the data you want to inject, or an error state.

So in your 'getColors.php' file I would change it to this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="container">
            <h1>Selecteer een Kleur</h1>
            <form method="post">
                <select id="select_color" name="autokleur">
                <?php

                    $AutoID = intval($_GET['AutoID']);

                //    mysqli_select_db($con,"Kleuren, Autos");
                    $sql1= "SELECT * FROM Kleuren INNER JOIN Autos ON Kleuren.AutoID = Autos.AutoID WHERE Kleuren.AutoID = '".$AutoID."'";
                    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);

                    if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {

                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
                            $Kleur = $row['KleurID'];
                            $Kleur2 = $row['Kleur'];
                            echo "<option value='$Kleur'>" . $row["Kleur"] . "</option>";

                        }

                        echo "</br>";
                        echo "<input id='VerzendOpties' name='VerzendBT' type='submit' value='Verzenden'>";
                    }
                    else
                        {
                            if ($result1->num_rows == 0){

                                // NOW RETURN AN ERROR STATE!
                                header('HTTP/1.1 500 Query error');

                                // Using die you can even return an error message if you want
                                die('<b>Er zijn geen kleuren gevonden!  </b></br><b>Je query is niet goed.</b></br>');

                            }
                        }

                 ?>


                </select>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then the 500 error can be picked up in your main javascript file

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("Autos").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            } else if (this.status === 500 {
                KleurError();
            }
        };
```

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help btw, but i don't get the 500 error afterwards and the second <select> tag  does'nt show anymore.